# How to initialize a select with a selected value?

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component which calls a child component.

The parent :

```
<select-school-type class="form-control" required value="this.school_type_id" @selected="changeSchoolTypeId">></select-school-type>
```

The child :

```
<select v-on:change="$emit('selected', $event.target.value)" v-model="value">
      <option value="">{{ placeholder }}</option>
      <option :value="schoolType.id" v-for="(schoolType, index) in schoolTypes" :key="index">{{ schoolType.id }}</option>
  </select>
```

The parent can "send" a value to the child (it is the props I called 'value'). And the child must add the "selected" option to the correct item.

I tried a lot of things without success. It is my first components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

`value="this.school_type_id"`

`this` is not defined in the template area:

```
<select-school-type class="form-control" required value="school_type_id" @selected="changeSchoolTypeId"></select-school-type>
```

2. If you pass the prop without using`:`, (`value="school_type_id"`) `school_type_id` will be type of string. But here we like to pass the variable `school_type_id` → `:value="school_type_id"`
3. `v-model` in the child changes the prop `value`, which isn't allowed by vue. You should see a warning in the console: "Avoid changing props directly ....". Change it this way and perhaps it works as expected:

```
<select @change="$emit('selected', $event.target.value)" :selected="value">
      <option value="">{{ placeholder }}</option>
      <option :value="schoolType.id" v-for="(schoolType, index) in schoolTypes" :key="index">{{ schoolType.id }}</option>
  </select>
```

If you like to use `v-model` instead, you can bind a computed getter/setter to it's value: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter
In the setter, you emit the new value:

```
computed: {
  selectedValue: {
    get() {
      return this.value;
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.$emit('selected', newValue);
    },
  },
},
```

```
<select v-model="selectedValue">
      <option value="">{{ placeholder }}</option>
      <option :value="schoolType.id" v-for="(schoolType, index) in schoolTypes" :key="index">{{ schoolType.id }}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks JohMun for your answer. I like your "compute" solution. I tried and unfortunately does not work. I think my problem is here : value="school_type_id" . I continu to read the docs...

Comment: Solved ! the parent sent the string 'school_type_id' . I must use :value="school_type_id". And now with the computed column, it works fine. Thanks JohMun.